# CakePHP 2.0 HABTM Model Filename

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have two tables/models (messages and users) that are combined by a HABTM table (messages_users)
Everything works right, but I need to make a change to the default model for MessagesUser.

What should the filename for the model be?

I have tried every thing I can think of:

> MessageUsers.php
>
> MessagesUsers.php
>
> Messages_Users.php
>
> ...

I have my code working because I check in `AppModel.php` in the constructor if it is constructing MessagesUser and if so I make the change, but this isn't a very clean way to write code.

Answer (score 1):

The filenames for model classes are always the same as the model itself, in this case MessagesUser.php.

Comment: Thank You!  I had tried MessagesUser.php.  It didn't work because I had the class named "MessageUser" and not "MessagesUser".